# Impala behaviour when using RAND() is...strange

Tags: cloudera-cdh, impala

I'm running the following query using Impala on CDH 5.3.0:

```
select *
from (
  select rand() as a 
  from tuk_pob.rp_model1_latest
)q
where q.a < 0.9
limit 15
```

When I run it I see this:
[image: impala strange behaviour]
Now I'm aware there are problems with RAND() (good discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/impala-user/QfEf68_ej8s)) but even if rand() behaves strangely the fact that I'm putting it into a subquery and filtering on the result should mean this should still work, shouldn't it? Well, clearly not, but I'd like to get an explanation as to why.

Can anyone tell me why the value 0.9421206940627288 is appearing in my resultset when it should have been filtered out?